# How to write a void function expression in typescript for react (using arrow function)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Unable to use the following expression in a react component:

```
<MyComponent updateCallback={() => void} />
```

However, this works fine:

```
<MyComponent updateCallback={() => false} />
```

Getting error in editor:

> *Expression expected*

In typescript, I am allowed to write following interface:

```
interface IProps {
  update: () => void;
}`
```

What is the correct approach for achieving above behaviour **without declaring and using it as an interface**?

Comment: `() => {}` should be equivalent to your "void" function - does something like `updateCallback={() => {}}` work?

Comment: @IainShelvington This works if I declare my interface as () => void; But editor gives error if I declare my interface also as () => {}. How come?

Comment: Because `() => {}` as a type annotation means a function that takes no arguments and returns an empty object, not a function that returns nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> updateCallback={() => void}

The reason this doesn't work is that that isn't valid javascript. There is a [void](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void) keyword, but it doesn't get used like this.

The typescript type `void` is not directly related to the javascript void. When a function has a type `update: () => void;`, that basically means that whoever calls this function promises not to do anything with the return value. Typically that means you'll return undefined, as in:

```
updateCallback={() => { return undefined; }}
```

Or an implicit return:

```
updateCallback={() => {}}
```

But if you return something else like `false`, that's still ok, since the caller will ignore that false.

---

Going back to the original code you wrote:

```
updateCallback={() => void}
```

If you want to have the return type be a typescript void, but you don't want to do an interface for the props, you would do a colon and then a return type, and in the body of the function you do whatever you want.

```
updateCallback={(): void => {}}
```